# Could not Sending All images from Android to flutter

Tags: flutter

```
byte[] Renderer(String path)
  {
     File file = new File(path);
     byte [] byteArray=null;
     String ans="empty";
    try
    {

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {

      //code for converting pages to images
    }
     return byteArray;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      byte[] h=null;
    return h;
    } 
}
```

I have Created Renderer method for converting  10 pages to PNG image and  send  to the  main.dart I  have received only the last   page but I want to display  all the pages  in my dart file.

Comment: please be concise https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Java `for` loop, you process each page but discard all but the last - you make a new `byteArray` for each page.

One solution is to return a list of all of the pages. In Java first declare an `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList bitmaps = new ArrayList();
```

Inside the for loop, add the compression result to the list:

```
bitmaps.add(outStream.toByteArray());
```

Finally, return `bitmaps`, rather than `byteArray`.

At the Dart end, you'll now get a `List<Uint8List>` rather than a single `Uint8List`, so change the signature of the method to:

```
Future<List<Uint8List>> pdfAsset() async
```

Obviously, you'll have to change the build method to deal with a list of bitmaps (one for each page) rather than a single bitmap (the last page).

(You may find that you need to change the signature to `Future<List<dynamic>>`, but you'll find that each of them is a `Uint8List`. Also, change the Java catch code to return an empty list.)